# eclipse product invocation causes java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found

Tags: export, eclipse-rcp, product

I just exported a product that is working nicely if I hit the "Launch an Eclipse application" button. If try to execute the exported product, I get following exception on the startup:

```
!SESSION 2012-03-16 17:28:21.206 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_26
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-03-16 17:28:22.184
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Just before I exported the product, I performed a validation of the dependencies and it was fine. Do you have a clue what is going wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, I would look for the following:

- you are not exporting the exact same set of plug-ins in your product configuration as used in the launch configuration. There are no tools available for the compare.
- you have a custom `config.ini` file that does not define the proper application for the product.

Comment: thank you. I checked the settings for the`config.ini` and I did not customize it.

Comment: Try to debug the exported product with the remote java debugging in Eclipse and add the -console argument. Then see which plug-ins are actually provisioned in the product and their state using the OSGi "ss" command.

Comment: I tried with following command `./eclipse -consoleLog -vmargs -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044`. I don't have the ability to try the 'ss' command since the message appears immediately and the VM terminates. The eclipse folder just contains configuration and plugins folder and the executable file eclipse. This is kind of strange since I'm used to have more files in the root eclipse folder. Thank you, for your help!

Comment: If you add the switch -noexit, the VM won't terminate and you can do a little forensic "ss"-ing.

Comment: Thank you Tonny and stracka. Afterwards I used `diag ID` on my plug-ins to figure out witch dependency could not be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Added missing javax.xml dependency to the product configuration file:

```
<plugin id="com.ibm.icu"/>
<plugin id="javax.annotation"/>
<plugin id="javax.inject"/>
+<plugin id="javax.xml"/>
<plugin id="org.apache.batik.css"/>
<plugin id="org.apache.batik.util"/>
<plugin id="org.apache.batik.util.gui"/>
```

Comment: I also added it to the run configuration in order to make it work

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
With E4 tooling the following steps worked for me.
Open .product file and go to Dependencies tab. Then press Add Required Plug-ins.
Then go to Overview and press Launch an Eclipse application.
Also you should do Help->Check for updates

Answer (score 2):

I went to my **run configurations** and hit `Add Required Plug-Ins` one the `Plug-Ins` page. Made the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar exception while launching my project. In my case, the reason was JRE version - I've set JRE 1.7 instead of 1.6 in debug configuration, and things started to work. I believe the same thing can happen, if the project was configured for OpenJDK 1.6, and the debug launches it with sun-JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Review the Dependencies tab, and remove the extra plug-ins are are showing un-resolved in the Plug-ins and Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means, that when launching an eclipse Program the id of the selected product in the run configuration is not preset in the set of your plugins:

[image: Run Configuration in Eclipse or Obeo]