# Im trying to run eclipse for the first time and im getting an error

Tags: eclipse

I have eclipse 3.0.1 installed on this p.c. This is an organization pc, therefore the gpo doesnt allow me to dl anything on this p.c.

When i try to run eclipse i am getting an error that sends me to check the log file.

Tried to google it but didnt find any solution. 
Any ideas?

Here is the log file:

```
!SESSION 24, 2016 06:32:41.232 ---------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M200409161125
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 24, 2016 06:32:41.232
!MESSAGE Product org.eclipse.platform.ide could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi יול 24, 2016 06:32:41.242
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run     
(Unknown     Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:185)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:704)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:688)
```

Comment: Try to see if this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741125/eclipse-product-invocation-causes-java-lang-runtimeexception-no-application-id fixes your problem.

Comment: Try using eclipse 4.6(neon). The version you are using is very old 12 years to be exact.

Comment: Eclipse 3.0.1 is extremely old and doesn't even support Java 5 language features never mind Java 8. If you want to use Eclipse you really need to find a way to run something much newer.