# "No application id has been found" after running eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am migrating a RCP application from eclipse 3(Indigo) to eclipse 4(Mars).
I have resolved all the dependencies related issues. But I am not able to launch the product file using "Launch an eclipse application".

**The error is:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

If I go to Run -> Run Configuration -> Add Required Plugins and the Run the application from there. The application runs.

Can anyone please tell me where the settings or entry of those newly added plugins gets stored upon clicking "Add Required Plugins" button(AFAIK it selects those plugins on-the-fly) ? Because after running the application again from "Launch an eclipse application". It doesn't start. I get the same error. How can I persist the list of newly added plugins for next build(from "Launch an eclipse application")

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of non-persisting plugins, even after adding required plugins from Run Configuration.

User Dan Nick had the fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16011871/5005462

Essentially, it seems necessary to Add Required Plug-ins on the *product* Dependencies tab as well. Once I did this, and then clicked "Launch an Eclipse application" from the product Overview tab, the application launched successfully.